# Xcode Failed to create a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an `iOS` app I am trying to develop and test in `Xcode`. However, I get the error below.  I do not have a physical Apple device, but would like to test this on an `iOS Simulator`. I thought this should launch a Simulator if I press the **play** button, as I have selected `iPhone 6s Plus` for example, but it just says "Build Succeeded" and does nothing.

**Question**

How do I resolve the errors below, and test the app on a Simulator?

Thanks

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because of Provisioning profile or Automatic manage signing.

You've selected the wrong target, Please select the target as '**theWhoZoo**' (which is beside Run & Stop button at the top) and run on `Simulator` again.

While running on `Simulator`, you don't need *the Provisioning profile or Automatic manage signing*.

As shown in image below:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked just turning off 'Automatically manage signing'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they didn't give you full account access. Check if this link:

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/

Show this pop-up

[image]