# XCode: failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, sign

I'm using XCode to develop a simple app. XCode asks me to register a device into my developer account (see the picture). So I was wondering if to sign a simple app, I would need to own (or purchase) an iphone/ipad.
Can it depend on whether the "personal" certificate is targeted to sign the app on personal devices only? 
If I enroll in the development program, things could change ?

[image: Xcode]

Comment: change your target scheme simulator to generic device .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to create provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603667/failed-to-create-provisioning-profile)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Failed to create a provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759674/xcode-failed-to-create-a-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 0):

```
1 - have u created an app id in developer.apple.com
2 - if u have done that check bundle identifier
3 - try changing team or check preference -> account ->  check credentials of apple ids
```

Comment: 1) Yes I have an AppID, but I haven't enrolled in to the payed program

2) What's could be wrong in the bundle identifier ?

3) In the Account preferences, I read my name near "Personal Team", role "User"

Answer (score 0):

Possible Cases .

1. You need to add account to your xcode preferences .
2. Change your target setting from simulator to Generic Device .

[image]

Comment: Yes I have added an account Account in the Xcode preferences. I read my name near "Personal Team", role "User"

Comment: then try second case.